# Palette Library not picking color on linear layout

Tags: android, palette

I am using Palette Library for picking dominant color. My swatch is giving right TitleTextColor but not giving RGB color. I am using rgb color to apply background of linear layout

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapCompress.decodeBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mihawk, 360, 360);
Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();
Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = p.getDominantSwatch();
LinearLayout top;
top = findViewById(R.id.wallpaperLinearLayoutTop);
top.setBackgroundColor(vibrantSwatch.getRgb());
```

Here is Xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperLinearLayoutTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: what does `Integer.toHexString(vibrantSwatch.getRgb())` return?

Comment: @pskink logcat value is negative integer "-8355712"

Comment: no, its not hex string

Comment: also what do you see on the logcat if you `Log.d` the value of `vibrantSwatch.toString()`?

Comment: @pskink returning this..."ff808080" and I think this cant be color hex

Comment: so you have the perfect grey color (#f888)

Comment: @pskink yeah.. but this is not dominant color in my picture and its showing same for all pictures. this grey color

Comment: ok, setup a breakpoint here: `Palette p = ....` and press `View Bitmap` on the right side of `bitmap` variable in your debugger, what do you see?

Comment: @pskink sorry but dont know how to do that. new to development

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: @pskink okk give me some time

Comment: @pskink got the problem thnkxx man. LinearLayout contains 2 textview which had background.